# Fast self collision/intersection detection algorithm for tetrahedral meshes

Tags: collision-detection, 3d, algorithm, intersection

I want to play with deformation of tetrahedral mesh (soft-body simulation) but I need help with self-collision detection stuff.

I found [SOFA collision detection](https://www.sofa-framework.org/community/doc/simulation-principles/multi-model-representation/collision/#collision-detection) but I'm not sure that it fits for self-intersection of a tetrahedral mesh.

Can anyone suggest me good algorithm for self-collision detection? As far as I can understand, something like BVH of tetrahedra can help me, but it would be great if somebody with expertise shows me right direction.

Comment: Wouldn't any collision detection algorithm that works with convex shapes apply here, after you filter out any tetrahedra sharing a face? (eg. Separating Axis Theorem or GJK, or even just plain triangle-triangle intersection tests for the surface faces alone) What is it about self-intersection specifically that makes this troublesome to solve with conventional methods?